# React form validation using html input properties

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

There are many fancy ways to validate form inputs in React
but is there a way to get a simple boolean which when a form is submitted tells me if all inputs in the form were valid according to html

html offers simple form validation techniques on input tags like `required`, `min`, `max` and even complex ones like `pattern` and I'd like to very much use these.

Is there any way I can simply check if a bunch of inputs are valid according to html and get a boolean output according to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ***The answer to your question is in the end, thought i would share some insight before hand***

its not practical or best practice to validate each input all at once,what you can do in vanilla JS/React is set states for or onChange functions for each input field, and do validations in seperate functions for each, if you want to get super basic, you can use the req, min, max, etc, but sometimes thats even not enough, sometimes you need extra checks.

### Cons of using basic html validation:

Inconsistent Browser Support: Different browsers may have varying levels of support for HTML validation features. This can lead to inconsistent behavior across different browsers, potentially causing confusion for users or resulting in a poor user experience.

Lack of Accessibility: HTML validation messages are often not easily customizable for accessibility purposes. Customizing error messages to meet accessibility standards, such as providing clear instructions and using appropriate ARIA attributes, can be more challenging with HTML validation alone.

Limited Cross-Field Validation: HTML validation is typically limited to validating individual input fields. If you need to perform validation that involves multiple fields, such as comparing two fields or validating based on complex business logic, HTML validation may not be sufficient.

Handling Errors: HTML validation primarily relies on browser-specific UI and error messages, which may not align with your application's styling or error handling conventions. It can be difficult to provide a consistent user experience for form validation errors across your application using only HTML validation.

### How to expand

you can use onChange functions, and useState in react functional components to validate as you go. if you have a form and even one thing is wrong on what you want the data to be, but the html validation says its correct, then you wont get what you want.

### How i do it

i do forms both multistep and small forms alot, what i like to do is use as onchage and states like i stated earlier and validate each input as the user goes through the form, once the person presses next on multistep, the validation kicks in and doesnt allow, same thing with small forms.

You have alot more control and alot stronger validation when you use your own + the html premade validation.

## Answering your question:

Yes, you can use the built-in HTML form validation and check if all inputs in the form are valid using the checkValidity() method. The checkValidity() method is available on the HTMLFormElement and can be used to determine if all the fields in the form meet their validation criteria.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const MyFormComponent = () => {
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const isFormValid = formRef.current.checkValidity();

    if (isFormValid) {
      // Do something when the form is valid
      console.log('Form is valid! Submitting...');
      formRef.current.reset();
    } else {
      // Do something when the form is not valid
      console.log('Form is not valid. Please check your inputs.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" required />
      </label>
      <label>
        Age:
        <input type="number" name="age" required min="18" max="99" />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyFormComponent;
```

you can use the `checkValidity()` method on the form element (`formRef.current`) when the form is submitted. The method returns true if all input fields with the required, min, max, and pattern attributes are valid according to the HTML validation rules. If any field fails validation, it returns false.

Comment: very insightful, thanks

Comment: Hi, I wanted to ask if it was possible to see where the errors have occured in terms of inputs or atleast trigger the html popup which happens in vanilla html if incorrect form is submitted there is a popup on the invalid inputs.